# Can Minecraft for Windows 10 create Map Markers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have read about creating a Map Marker with Bedrock edition v. 1.9.15: create a banner, create a locator map, and point the map at the banner and right-click.
But, when I do that, nothing happens. I thought that Windows 10 version was part of Bedrock edition. I go to the Windows Store and it says I have the latest edition.

Anyone know?

Comment: welcome to Arqade. i'm assuming you was talking about Minecraft so i added the tag. in future take a bit of time to find an game tag or mention it in your question, otherwise people would close the question as unclear

Comment: I edited your post, but don't really know what version you are referring to, as [I cannot find](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Java_Edition_version_history) a Minecraft version 1.9.15. Are you sure that's the right version?

Comment: Memor-X, I tried to add tags.  But, it said I needed some sort of 'score' of 300 to add them.  Thanks for adding the tag.

Comment: Joachim, it is the version one downloads from Microsoft Store.  In reading, it says it is part of Bedrock edition.  It has 'Realms' so am thinking it is part of that.

Answer (score 2):

Banners work to mark on maps in Java Edition, but unfortunately not in Bedrock.

You can create a map, then duplicate it and leave one in a frame where you want to have a marker, then take the copy to where you also want a marker, the 2 maps should then both have the markers on them.

I have tested this in 3 areas around the world, which are working, but left a map further away - again all copies of my main map, but there is one that doesn't show up.